# How do I provide a full stack trace with an ACRA error report in Android?

Tags: android, acra

I have an app where I use ACRA for error reporting.

I recently decided to send a caught exception with ErrorReporter, and it works, albeit without any kind of stack trace. All I get is the usual system dump info, and I really need the stack traces from my users.

So, my question is, how do I have the app send the full details?

(Note: When the app actually crashes completely, the error report sent by ACRA does include the stack trace.)

Here's a screenshot: [screenshot](http://i.troll.ws/2861d874.png)

**EDIT**

I kept looking deeper in the reports, and as it turns out, ACRA's just reporting the stack trace to another column that's never really been used before: tags. So, perhaps just a bug or something in ACRA.

Comment: Have you read the documentation here https://github.com/ACRA/acra.

Comment: Yes I have. I should clarify; **automatic error reporting works fine.** The only thing that doesn't work completely is explicitly reporting a caught exception.

Comment: "how do I have the app send the full details?" What does it means what more details you need.    "the error report sent by ACRA does include the stack trace" yes it does please check the "STACK TRACE column in you doc"

Comment: When the app full-on crashes and force closes, I get a full stack trace in that column, but with a caught exception, all I get is a timestamp, e.g. "2013-03-11T22:22:43.000-06:00". I'm looking to get the full logcat output, like I do with a crash.

Comment: you have specified only timestamp, does it meant you have only timestap column in you doc (.csv file which we are imported in google drive) contains Timestamp,
REPORT_ID,
APP_VERSION_CODE,
APP_VERSION_NAME,.... like this 31 columns "stack trace" is one among them which have log cat message.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not being clear enough; the timestamp is **in** the stack trace column.

Comment: but stack trace column does not contain any time stamp it contains only error message.

Comment: Exactly! I need to see the stack trace, but it's only including the timestamp, which shouldn't even be there in the first place.

Comment: As you see the screenshot of kaushal trivedi. Could you attach yours the same way?

Comment: @vinaykumar: Just added a link to the OP, I don't have the reputation to directly embed an image.

Comment: Yes I see! it is a issue. But unable to understand the cause, If you get the chance delete the existing one and import the new .csv file. lets see if it resolve for this

Comment: one more doubt how long you are facing this issue. because i see 1330 forms in your doc

Comment: I only started manually reporting exceptions last week, and the HUGE majority of these reports are much older than that, and they have the stack trace in the proper column.

Comment: Yes I am using ARC in one of my application they do have their stack trace in proper column. I recommend to used latest .csv file and the related library too.

Answer (score 1):

You should follow the ACRA tutorial and full instruction guide page.
All you need is to create a from in google docs account . After creating a form a key will be generated that you have to save it and apply it in your application java file of you android  application project.With minor changes in manifest and application java file you can successfully integrate ACRA.

Follow the given link.
https://github.com/ACRA/acra/wiki/BasicSetup

it will come in STACK_TRACE column of your form like these

[image]

Comment: Please see my response to vinaykumar.

Answer (score 0):

ACRA.getErrorReporter().handleException(caughtException);

See https://github.com/ACRA/acra/wiki/AdvancedUsage#wiki-Sending_reports_for_caught_exceptions